# How do I use an embedded font in C#?

Tags: c#, fonts

I've looked at a few pages on here, MSDN, and around the web, and this still isn't quite clear to me. I'm looking to embed a font in a Windows Forms package then use that font in a Graphics.DrawString method using C#.
What I have managed to do so far is add the font to Resources then embed it into a PrivateFontCollection using:

```c#
PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
```

and in the constructor:

```c#
privateFontCollection.AddFontFile("Properties.Resources.C_C_Red_Alert__LAN_");
```

The code I want it in is:

```c#
Graphics w = Graphics.FromImage(box.boxImage);
w.DrawString("Hello World!", (privateFontCollection.C_C_Red_Alert__LAN_, 22), Brushes.Black, new PointF(16, 16));
```

I hope I have included enough information to make myself clear.

Comment: Use PrivateFontColletion.Families to get the FontFamily you can pass to the Font constructor.

Comment: @HansPassant I managed to get your suggestion to work but now it's telling me the file specified in the AddFontFile isn't working. I can tell you its real name and its location if you don't mind clarifying what exact location it wants. The file is called "C&C Red Alert [LAN].ttf" and is in the Resources folder, and Visual Studio has given it the name "C_C_Red_Alert__LAN_" in its own Resources list.